# Python - print 2nd argument

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I've written this test-code for practicing purposes, in order to find and print email addresses from various web pages:

```
def FindEmails(*urls):
    for i in urls:
         totalemails = []
         req = urllib2.Request(i)
         aResp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
         webpage = aResp.read()
         patt1 = '(\w+[-\w]\w+@\w+[.]\w+[.\w+]\w+)'
         patt2 = '(\w+[\w]\w+@\w+[.]\w+)'
         regexlist = [patt1,patt2]
         for regex in regexlist:
             match = re.search(regex,webpage)
             if match:
                 totalemails.append(match.group())
                 break
    #return totalemails
    print "Mails from webpages are: %s  " % totalemails

if __name__== "__main__":
    FindEmails('https://www.urltest1.com', 'https://www.urltest2.com')
```

When I run it, it prints only one argument.
My goal is to print the emails acquired from webpages and store them in a list, separated by commas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the line: `totalemails = []`. Here, you are re-instantiating the the variables `totalemails` to have zero entries. So, in each iteration, it only has one entry inside it. After the last iteration, you'll end up with just the last entry in the list. To get a list of all emails, you need to put the variable outside of the `for` loop.
Example:

```
def FindEmails(*urls):
    totalemails = []
    for i in urls:
         req = urllib2.Request(i)
         ....
```

Comment: one detail that solved my problem! thanks a lot r3ign and stackoverflow!!